# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException at android app

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

My app crashed yesterday on my phone, at google developer the error is the following:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=69; regionStart=21; regionLength=-20 
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)   
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
at com.somjah.radio.RadioService.getTrackFromAAC(RadioService.java:998)
at com.somjah.radio.RadioService.access$10(RadioService.java:985) 
at com.somjah.radio.RadioService$1.playerMetadata(RadioService.java:953)
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.IcyInputStream.parseMetadata(IcyInputStream.java:231)
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.IcyInputStream.fetchMetadata(IcyInputStream.java:205)  
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.IcyInputStream.read(IcyInputStream.java:133)
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.BufferReader.run(BufferReader.java:155)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is part the part of RadioService.java:

```
@Override

public void playerMetadata(String key, String value) {

System.out.println("Metadata--------------");

System.out.println(key + " ==> " + value);

            if ("StreamTitle".equals(key) || "icy-name".equals(key)

|| "icy-description".equals(key)) {
            final String meta_artist = getArtistFromAAC(value);

            final String meta_track = getTrackFromAAC(value);

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

@Override
            public void run() {

            updateMetadataTitle(meta_artist, meta_track);

            }

            });


}

}

@Override

public void playerAudioTrackCreated(AudioTrack arg0) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

};

    private String getArtistFromAAC(String streamTitle) {

    int end = streamTitle.indexOf("-");

    if (end <= 0)

    end = streamTitle.indexOf(":");

        String title;

        if (end > 0)

        title = streamTitle.substring(0, end);

    else

            title = streamTitle;

        return title.trim();

    }


private String getTrackFromAAC(String streamTitle) {

        int start = streamTitle.indexOf("-") + 1;

        if (start <= 0)

        start = streamTitle.indexOf(":") + 1;


String track;

        if (start > 0)

        track = streamTitle.substring(start);

        else

        track = streamTitle;

        int end = streamTitle.indexOf("(");

        if (end > 0)

        track = streamTitle.substring(start, end); //this is line 998

        end = streamTitle.indexOf("[");

        if (end > 0)

        track = streamTitle.substring(start, end);

        return track.trim();

    }


}
```

I think the error is in the last lines, but I cant figure out. What is missing?

Comment: How about using `{}` brackets for your if else blocks for better readability? Also please indicate where is line `RadioService.java:998` ?

Comment: one possible explanation can be - the streamtitle variable contains '(' before "-" / ":", makes value of end variable less than start variable...

Comment: @donfuxx I commented the above code where line 998 is.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace we can see the exception is coming from the method getTrackFromAAC() line 998, your call to substring(). The exception indicates you are passing substring() invalid parameters. [This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) provides information on valid parameters for subString().

You are probably getting this exception because you are passing in a String where "(" appears before "-". You could try changing your final if statement to

```
if (end > 0 && start < end)
```

to avoid this exception from occurring

Comment: I have updated my answer - please check your input data and ensure that you are not entering strings where "(" appears before "-"

Comment: well, the getTrack function takes de Track name of the mp3 song. So if a song has "(nameofsong)" that what is causing the error if that is what you mean. I can remove the substring of ( and leave only the [. what would you suggest? thanks!

Comment: here I have a clue I tested the app and when I was streaming a song with the following track name it crashed (NAVIBE com TioBad - seg/sex 10:00 às 16:00). So when the mp3 song is already with ( crash the app

Comment: I added the line you suggested if (end > 0 && start < end) to both if end the one with ( and the one with [ now the app is working thanks!